# Pop up form for every post's custom button Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

There are multiple custom posts displaying on a page, post type is 'property', in which I putted a button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">Submit Offer</button>
```

This button is in a loop and getting displayed below every post. What I want is to pop up a custom html form which should contain Post ID as hidden field.

This is how Post ID and title is getting fetched on post's listing page:

```
global $post;
global $wpdb;
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'property'
) );
$id = $the_query->post->ID;
$title = get_the_title( $id );
```

HTML FORM:

```
<h2 class="text center">
                Submit Your Offer
            </h2>
            <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-md-12"  for="Name"><?php  esc_html_e( 'Name', 'ivproperty' ); ?><span class="red-star">*</span></label>
            <input  class="col-md-12" id="name" name ="name" type="text" required>
     </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="email" class="col-md-12"><?php  esc_html_e( 'Email', 'ivproperty' ); ?><span class="red-star">*</span></label>
             <input class="col-md-12"  name="email" type="text" required>
     </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="price" class="col-md-12"><?php  esc_html_e( 'Price', 'ivproperty' ); ?><span class="red-star">*</span></label>
             <input class="col-md-12"  name="price" type="number" required>
     </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="purchase_type" class="col-md-12"><?php  esc_html_e( 'Purchase Type', 'ivproperty' ); ?><span class="red-star">*</span></label>
<select class="col-md-12" name="purchase_type" required>
  <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
  <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
  <option value="Conventional Loan">Conventional Loan</option>
  <option value="FHA Loan">FHA Loan</option>
  <option value="MSHDA Conventional Loan">MSHDA Conventional Loan</option>
  <option value="MSHDA FHA Loan">MSHDA FHA Loan</option>
  <option value="Land Contract">Land Contract</option>
</select>
     </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    
                        <label for="closing_date"><?php  esc_html_e( 'Closing Date', 'ivproperty' ); ?><span class="red-star">*</span></label>
             <input class="col-md-12 date_box"  name="closing_date" type="date" required>   
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="closing_date"><?php  esc_html_e( 'Concessions Amount', 'ivproperty' ); ?></label>
                        <input class="col-md-12"  name="concessions_amount" type="number">
                        
     </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="closing_date" class="col-md-12"><?php  esc_html_e( 'Inspection Period', 'ivproperty' ); ?><span class="red-star">*</span></label>
             <input class="col-md-6 date_box"  name="insp_from" type="date" required>
                    <input class="col-md-6 date_box"  name="insp_to" type="date" required>
     </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="closing_date" class="col-md-12"><?php  esc_html_e( 'Seller Occupancy & Charge', 'ivproperty' ); ?></label>
             <input class="col-md-6"  name="seller_occupancy" type="text" placeholder="Occupancy">
                    <input class="col-md-6"  name="seller_charge" type="number" placeholder="Charge">
     </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="price" class="col-md-12"><?php  esc_html_e( 'EMD', 'ivproperty' ); ?><span class="red-star">*</span></label>
             <input class="col-md-12"  name="emd" type="number" placeholder="Earnest Money Deposit" required>
     </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="warranty" class="col-md-12"><?php  esc_html_e( 'Home Warranty', 'ivproperty' ); ?><span class="red-star">*</span></label>
<select class="col-md-12" name="home_warranty" required>
  <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
  <option value="Conventional Loan">Yes</option>
  <option value="FHA Loan">No</option>
</select>
     </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="price" class="col-md-12"><?php  esc_html_e( 'Attachment', 'ivproperty' ); ?></label>
             <input type="file" name="attachment">
     </div>
                
                 <div class="modal-footer">                 
                                        
                            <input type="submit" name="submit_offers" class="btn btn-secondary col-md-12 ml-2">                     
                        </div>  
</form>
```

Also I wanted to process this form inside pop-up only as ajax and display the success message.

Can Anyone help?

Comment: thanks, can you please answer my question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery 'dialog' to open a popup with your form.

Simply embed your form in a div with an id and convert it into a dialog.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" id="but" >Open Popup</button>

<div id="dialogForm">
    <form id="myform" method="post">
        Name:
        <input type="text"/><br/>
        Phone:
        <input type="text"/><br/>
        <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#but').click(function() {
      $("#dialogForm").dialog("open");
   });
   $("#dialogForm").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: true,
        show: {effect: "blind", duration: 800}
    });
```

**JavaScript for loading the dialog on load of the homepage** Note that the 'autoOpen' is set to true.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sve3Lmje/

Fiddle for opening dialog without click: http://jsfiddle.net/sve3Lmje/1/